# positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument

Tags: powershell

```
if ($mbcb1.Checked -eq $true) {$dgr = "-AutoStart"}

if ($mbcb2.Checked -eq $true) {$dgrc = "-AutoComplete"}

if ($mbcb3.Checked -eq $true) {$dgren = "-NotificationEmails"}

New-MigrationBatch -Name $mbnd -SourceEndpoint $mbcx -TargetDeliveryDomain $mbtdd -CSVData ([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("$cmbcsvfile")) $dgr $dgrc $dgren admin@admin.com


Error : 
A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '-Autostart'.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-MigrationBatch], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,New-MigrationBatch
    + PSComputerName        : ps.outlook.com
```

if i given direct input its working but passing as variable throwing error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to optionally specify parameters, use splatting:

```
$OptionalParameters = @{
  AutoStart = $mbcb1.Checked
  AutoComplete = $mbcb2.Checked
}
if ($mbcb3.Checked) {
  $OptionalParameters["NotificationEmails"] = 'admin@admin.com'
}

New-MigrationBatch -Name $mbnd -SourceEndpoint $mbcx -TargetDeliveryDomain $mbtdd -CSVData ([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("$cmbcsvfile")) @OptionalParameters
```

We simply build a hashtable with the parameter names and their arguments, and then supply it to the cmdlet as an argument (but like `@name` instead of `$name`), and then the parser will turn each entry in the hashtable into a named parameter in the form `-key:value`.
Finally, the `$mbcb3.Checked -eq $true` comparison is redundant, since `Checked` (assuming that `$mbcb3` is a checkbox) is already either `$true` or `$false`

See the [`about_Splatting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about_Splatting?view=powershell-5.0) help file for more details about parameter splatting